# Ordered result from unnest() function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

There is guarantee that function `unnest()` will be return values in these order, how they are located?

That is, for exmple from this:

```
arr (INTEGER[])
---------------
{{3,5},{33,3}}
```

This query:

`SELECT unnest(arr) FROM "table"`

Always will be return

```
 3
 5
 33
 3
```

?

Or may be result will be ordered differently, than array  elements are ordered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's helpful link for you [UNNEST result order vs Array data](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/UNNEST-result-order-vs-Array-data-td5760087.html).

Here's an assumption:

> An unnest() will almost certainly scan the array in-order, but once
>   you embed that in a large query the ordering is no longer guaranteed.

Quote from this thread:

> unnest() returns its output in the same order as the input.  Since an
>   array is ordered it will be returned in the same output order by
>   unnest.  However, since unnest() only returns a single column (though
>   possibly of a composite type) it cannot provide the row number in the
>   output thus in order to maintain the same order elsewhere in the query
>   it is necessary to use "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)" on the output of the
>   unnest() - and before joining it with any other unnest calls or tables
>   - before supplying it to the rest of the query.  The "WITH ORDINALITY" functionality proposed for 9.4 will cause the unnest() [and other]
>   function to output this additional column along with the usual output.
>   This is, I am pretty such, a usability enhancement that makes easier
>   something that can be done today using CTE/WITH and/or sub-queries.

Another useful links:

- [How do I preserve the order of the original elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-do-i-preserve-the-order-of-the-original-elements-in-an-unnested-array)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number)

Comment: @OTARIKI looks like unnest keeps elements in order, but there's no guarantee to that. You can use generate_subscripts to guarantee order